# "Sexual assault", come tradurlo

Tags: word-choice, translation, single-words

Buongiorno,

Sto cercando di tradurre in italiano la parola "sexual assault" in italiano, magari anche con le sue varie sottocategorie. Ho cercato nel dizionario ed ho trovato "assalto" per "assault" ma non ho trovato questa combinazione di parole. Qualcuno mi può per caso aiutare?

UPDATE: Grazie per le vostre risposte. Mi chiedo come si tradurrebbe questa parola nel caso dove c'è del contatto fisico, magari anche di tipo non sessuale, come potrebbe essere anche un abbraccio senza consento, o anche una carezza, in assenza di nudità, senza stupro, e come conseguenza la persona che commette questo atto viene incolpata di "sexual assault", oppure anche "grooming" per esempio. In questo caso, si potrebbe forse usare il termine "aggressione sessuale", o ci sono anche dei termini più idonei per descrivere questa situazione in termini sia giuridici che informali?

Grazie.

Comment: Cosa intendi con "pallida"?

Comment: @Benedetta - direi "squalllida".

Comment: Forse “parola”?

Answer (score 8):

La traduzione di ***[sexual assault](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/inglese-italiano/sexual-assault)*** che offre il Collins Dictionary è :

> - violenza carnale.

Il [De Mauro](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/violenza-carnale) definisce "violenza carnale" come:

> - delitto consistente nel costringere qcn. in modo violento a un rapporto sessuale.

La distinzione che [Wikipedia](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violenza_sessuale) fa tra  violenza sessuale e carnale mi sembra rispecchi sia la definizione in inglese che quella italiana:

> - La violenza sessuale (o stupro) è un delitto commesso da chi usa in modo illecito la propria forza, la propria autorità o un mezzo di sopraffazione costringendo con atti, prevaricazione o minaccia (esplicita o implicita) a compiere o a subire atti sessuali contro la propria volontà. ***Talvolta si definisce violenza carnale (nel caso abbia luogo un rapporto sessuale).***

La definizione in inglese da The Free Dictionary:

> [sexual assault](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sexual+assault) - a statutory offense that provides that it is a crime to knowingly cause another person to engage in an unwanted sexual act by force or threat; "***most states have replaced the common law definition of rape with statutes defining sexual assault"***

Answer (score 7):

Potresti usare l'espressione ***violenza sessuale*** , il termine ***[stupro](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/stupro_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)/)***, oppure anche ***violenza carnale*** o ***abuso sessuale***.

Answer (score 6):

Secondo la definizione del dizionario medico [Medscape](http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/806120-overview), **sexual assault** è traducibile con **aggressione sessuale** e si distingue dallo stupro e dall'abuso, perché oltre alla coercizione c'è come conseguenza (secondo la definizione) anche la lesione della vittima.

In [altri casi](https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/001955.htm) viene considerato come sinonimo di **rape**, quindi traducibile in italiano come **stupro**

Answer (score 3):

Se stai cercando un termine che copra comportamenti meno gravi di "stupro", come il caso di abbracci e carezze senza consenso, credo "molestie" sia il termine comunemente usato.